# View PDF preview - fit to screen (no scroll bars)

Tags: vue.js, pdf, iframe, fancybox

I have a PDF opening in an iFrame using Fancybox. Is it possible to width to screen so in a mobile portrait view, it shows the whole thing, albeit tiny?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can be interested with this example which I Posted September 17, 2015

https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/177368-how-to-get-reference-to-pdf-object-embeded-in-ie/

Firstly you should change size of iFrame Element.

In a second step you should inspect iFrame nad check how PDF object is embeded

For example this could look like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function rsChange ()
{
    var ax = document.all.TestObj;
    if ( ax.readyState == 4 )
    {
        if ( ax.IsInitialized == false )
        {
            window.setTimeout( "rsChange();", 100 );
        }
        else
        {
            ax.Server = "192.168.1.3";
            ax.Connect ();
        }
    }
}

</script>

<OBJECT language='javascript' ID='TestObj' CLASSID='CLSID:36D64AE5-6626-4DDE-A958-2FF1D46D4424' WIDTH='640px' HEIGHT='480px' onreadystatechange='rsChange();'></OBJECT>

<br><br><br>

Don't forget to do a "REGSVR32 UltraVncAx.dll", before viewing this page.<br>
The timer trick in the rsChange() function is required to get the windowful ActiveX initialized properly, before letting the ActiveX create the VNC client child window.

</body>
</html>
```

In such case you should change parameters in this following object:

```
<OBJECT language='javascript' ID='TestObj' CLASSID='CLSID:36D64AE5-6626-4DDE-A958-2FF1D46D4424' WIDTH='640px' HEIGHT='480px' onreadystatechange='rsChange();'></OBJECT>
```